# How to prevent php going back page after log out?

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, logout

I've protected page for 3 level user. level 1--> admin = datapegawai.phplevel 2--> owner
level 3--> employee. When I back it after logged out, this page (datapegawai.php) always back.
`<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user']);
session_destroy();echo"<meta http-equiv='refresh'content='0; url=login.php'>";?>`

http://pastebin.com/AvF0PmCk

Comment: Why not use `header("Location: login.php");`? It's much faster and simplier.

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't work.. please check http://pastebin.com/AvF0PmCk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ayuktia : You are destroying session. So when you pressing back. Browser is showing cached page. Do following things.

1) Pages which are behind the login, check if session exists. If not redirect it to login page.

2) Use headers that will tell browser not to cache pages which require authentication.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

3) Use header permanent redirection.

```
header("Location: login.php",TRUE,302); 
die();
```

Comment: Where page should I put it?

Comment: It should be at the top of the page. Be careful headers should be put before outputting anything to browser. Else it wont work

Comment: It dosn't work.. :'(

Comment: Are you checking the session on the page  which require authentication? Also you should tell browser not to cache these pages which require login. So put 1st and 2nd point on page which require login. Create one logout.php. On logout clicked, redirect to logout.php. Put code in 3rd point there. So from logout.php you will be redirecting user to login page

Comment: by the way what's /foo.php?

Comment: Its a file where you want to redirect to - Updated answer with exact php page where you want to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `echo"<meta`....

instead use

```
header("Location:MynewURL");
```

(and also after close ? > add a lot of

```
<!-- dummy -->
```

because IE doesn't recognize in a good way the header tag when it had less than some kb

Comment: did you add the lot of dummy?

what error shows?

Comment: No, I didn't. Where page should I put dummy?

Comment: in datapegawai.php before you close the last ?>

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\Users\Samsung_B9L\Documents\Xampp\htdocs\pegawai\datapegawai.php on line 9

Comment: sorry after, not before

Comment: it still doesn't work..

Comment: can you upload the content from koneksi.php? 
Maybe the error is there and we're looking in other side...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MN5yPpXp

Comment: please share index.php

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QUGZswNw

Comment: I insist... you should use this:
<?php session_start(); unset($_SESSION['user']); session_destroy();header("Location:index.php");?> 
and after add a lot of < !-- dummy -- >

Comment: Where I should put this code?

Comment: I've just put it in logout.php, but it doens't work..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/piy0K6Zj